# How to return a result from an Action in Java Play Framework?

Tags: java, controller, frameworks, action, playback

All my controllers use this `CheckDowntimeAction` which I created.

```
@Singleton
@With(CheckDowntimeAction.class)
public class MyController extends Controller {
}
```

As expected, on every request, the `CheckDowntimeAction` prints "I'm here!". but how do I abort inside the `CheckDowntimeAction` so that if the site is down, I return my own result which I create in the `CheckDowntimeAction`?

```
public class CheckDowntimeAction extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {
    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Request req) {
        logger.info("I'm here!");

        // just move along, nothing to see here
        return delegate.call(req);
    }
}
```

This works, but it prints the downtime result *AFTER* the `MyController` is already done running. I want it to run *BEFORE* the controller completes.

```
public class CheckDowntimeAction extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {
    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Request req) {
        if (downtime) {
           Result r = badRequest("Site is down");

           // before Play 2.7, this would have been:
           // return F.Promise.pure(badRequest(r));

           return delegate.call(req).thenApply(result -> r);
        }

        // just move along, nothing to see here
        return delegate.call(req);
    }
}
```

Note this is using Java Play 2.7 which uses Requests instead of Contexts, and F.Promise is no longer available. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaHttpContextMigration27

Comment: In Play 2.9, I use Action to check, if user is logged in, I use:             return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(unauthorized("error")); Pls see complete example here: https://github.com/ertra/play-framework-by-example/blob/master/app/controllers/actions/SecuredAPIAction.java

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.1/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html `F.Promise` is deprecated, it says to use `CompletableFuture.completedFuture` instead. What changed in Play 2.7 is that `F.Promise` was finally removed entirely.

I believe the correct Play 2.7 way is thus: `return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(r);`